# pre-commit is failing with "Expected a Config map but got a list"

Tags: pre-commit.com

I've been using the `pre-commit` tool for years! and it's worked great until recently when it started failing with a mysterious error message:

```
$ pre-commit run flake8 --all-files
An error has occurred: InvalidConfigError: 
==> File .pre-commit-config.yaml
=====> Expected a Config map but got a list
Check the log at /home/asottile/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

your particular case has been warning since july of 2020 with a message similar to this:

```
$ pre-commit run flake8 --all-files
[WARNING] normalizing pre-commit configuration to a top-level map.  support for top level list will be removed in a future version.  run: `pre-commit migrate-config` to automatically fix this.
flake8...................................................................Passed
```

fortunately, even if you've already upgrade to pre-commit 3.0 (which drops support for this format) you can still run `pre-commit migrate-config` which will update your configuration to a supported format:

```
$ pre-commit migrate-config
Configuration has been migrated.
$ pre-commit run flake8 --all-files
flake8...................................................................Passed
```

---

disclaimer: I authored pre-commit

Comment: This worked for me. The config with issues is https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/pre-commit.html .Perhaps an update to the docs is needed?

Comment: that documents things you would _add_ to your existing configuration